# Drawbacks of marked transactions in TFS 2010 backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tfs, database-backups

I wanted to see if you guys are utilizing marked transactions in your TFS backup scenario. Are there any drawbacks or gotchas to consider for this?

Answer (score 2):

If I use the TFS Power Tools to create a backup plan, the following is created for me:

- *Tables and Stored Procedures needed for marked transactions*
- Scheduled Jobs
- Maintenance Plans for Full, Differential, and Transaction Logs

> The Backup/Restore Power Tool relies on SQL marked transactions to
>   keep consistency across the TFS (and dependency products) databases. Source: http://intovsts.net/tag/tfs-power-tools/
>
> Before inserting named marks into the transaction log, consider the
>   following: Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx/)
>
> - Because transaction marks consume log space, use them only for
>     transactions that play a significant role in the database recovery
>     strategy.
> - After a marked transaction commits, a row is inserted in the
>     logmarkhistory table in msdb.
> - If a marked transaction spans multiple databases on the same database
>     server or on different servers, the marks must be recorded in the logs
>     of all the affected databases.

That kind of settles the matter of marked transactions in my backup plan. Especially since the TFS databases use full recovery mode, and the tool relies on it, there isn't much choice. :)

Comment: +100 this is how to set it up and has been since the first release, Your sources are not something you want to not be able to restore.